# creating a Neo4j node using java code

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to create a new node in the neo4j database graph.db using java, I am trying to execute this code:

```
GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
  GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("./users/rih/neo4j-2.2.5/data/graph.db");



try(Transaction tx=db.beginTx()){
    Node nod=db.createNode(NodeType.course);
    nod.setProperty("name", "comp");
    Node nodrim=db.createNode(NodeType.course);
    nod.setProperty("name", "info");

  }
```

But nothing is showing on the graph database,the nodes are not added.
pleaaasee help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that you commit the transaction-

```
tx.success()
```

Comment: can you share your updated code? and *what is not working* ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Luanne suggest  and a addition to it is to close the transaction if no further use is there. `tx.success(); tx.close();` transcation should be closed at the end.

Comment: It'll be closed anyway when using try with resources